# "Сегодняшний", "вчерашний" относится только к текущему дню?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Почему-то думал, что уже спрашивал это, но забыл, что мне ответили.

Надеюсь, что эти слова можно отнести не только к данному дню. Например, часто хочется сказать (и говоришь, только с сомнением, правильно ли это), что *какой-то (конкретный) хлеб (в магазине) редко бывает сегодняшним.* Или, если там есть упаковки за разные даты, что *среди них* редко есть сегодняшний. Или что *тот хлеб в лучшем случае вчерашний обычно.*

Можно так говорить, имея в виду сегодняшний или вчерашний день ***для какого-то любого времени?***

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его как принятый (зеленая галочка).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

О "вчерашнем" можно говорить в контексте, не связанном с отсчётом времени, когда это слово переносится на подразумеваемые свойства чего-то (как-то раз сдуру поел вчерашних щей, "вечно вчерашние" политики, "Кому нужны вчерашние газеты?" - песня Роллинг Стоунз, и т. п.). Если же требуется относительная ссылка на день из прошлого, то для привязки ко времени обычно требуются уточнения (накануне, днём ранее). "Сегодня" и "сегодняшний" заметно реже используются в упомянутом выше качестве (чаще приходится ссылаться на "тот день", утро того же дня" и пр.) - возможно, потому, что в слово встроен "день" и не образуется качества "сегодняшнести". В разговоре о минувшем дне возможно метафорическое понимание "сегодня" как современности, а также книжный перенос повествования из прошлого времени в настоящее (И вот тот день настал. Я предвкушал, как сегодня пойду в школу, хотя вчера в это ещё не верилось).

Comment: Спасибо, Александр! Ну хоть где-то можно хоть, хорошо.)